# Webrick and Apache in one server

Tags: ruby, apache, http, webrick

I have a server that runs an Apache server on port 80 and a Webrick web-apps on port 9090. Whenever I stop the Webrick server by killing the process using `kill -9 12345`, where `12345` is the PID of Webrick, I cannot restart the web-apps again since port 9090 is "automatically" used by another process, which is surprisingly the Apache server.

Currently, I have to stop and restart the Apache server before I can restart my Webrick web-apps, which is very annoying. Is there any better solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Switch the port for either webrick or apache.  Apache Tomcat defaults to port 9090.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I have tried other port e.g. 13131. And I still needed to stop and restart the Apache before restart the webrick web-apps. Btw, is there any dependency between webrick and apache?

Comment: Webrick is a self contained server for developing RoR apps; no relation to Apache.  What ports do you have Apache, Webrick, and Tomcat assuming that's on your box as well set to currently?

Comment: Apache 80, webrick 13131 (previously 9090), and I don't have Tomcat in my server.

Comment: Can you post your httpd.conf and webrick/config.rb files?

Comment: I set the webrick's config in the codes:

--- webserver.rb ---
address = "0.0.0.0"
port = 13131
server_type = WEBrick::Daemon
WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Host => address, :Port => port, :ServerType => server_type)


I copied the contents of two files which I think related with this problem i.e. ports.conf and sites-enabled/default:

--- ports.conf ---
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

--- sites-enabled/default ---
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ...
</VirtualHost>

Comment: FYI, I use Ubuntu 12.04, Apache 2.2.22, and Ruby 1.8.7. Apache and Ruby are the standard packages from Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Herry,  Internet has been out due to the blizzard here in the midwest.  Were you able to get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

with `kill -9 id` you really kill the process ... so it has no chance to say "good by". So apache has no chance to realize that the other end of connection is gone (or it takes a while)

try a simple `kill id` before and only use `kill -9` if the process hangs